# Continue querying Yahoo finance after a stock data request is rejected

Tags: python, error-handling, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance, stock

I'm trying to snatch data about some Swedish companies and with Python and Yahoo finance. When I get to some ticker such as `KIND-SDB.ST` I get

```
RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?a=1&ignore=.csv&s=KIND-SDB.ST&b=1&e=1&d=2&g=d&f=2017&c=2017
```

How do I get yahoo finance to snatch this data, and if I can't, how do I proceed with the rest of the list of tickers even though one is corrupt?

My little script looks like this:

```
start = datetime.date(2017,2,1)
end = datetime.date.today()


my_stocks = ['NEPA.ST','EVO.ST','KIND-SDB.ST','EVO.ST','ATCO-B.ST','KINV-B.ST','NDA-SEK.ST','SAND.ST','GRNG.ST','JM.ST','SAAB-B.ST','STAR-B.ST','ASSA-B.ST','INVE-B.ST','INDU-C.ST','SKF-B.ST']

pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 4)   # Change the size of plots



def stockplotter(ticker,start,end,numb):
    stock = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker,start,end)
    plt.figure(numb)
    stock["Adj Close"].plot(grid = True)
    plt.title(ticker)
    plt.ylabel('SEK@close')
    numb+=1

numb = 1
for i in my_stocks:

    stockplotter(i, start, end, numb)
    numb += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To continue querying the API after an error is raised, you need to [catch and handle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#index-0) the exception.

```
def stockplotter(ticker,start,end,numb):
    try:
        stock = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker,start,end)
    except RemoteDataError:
        pass

    plt.figure(numb)
    stock["Adj Close"].plot(grid = True)
    plt.title(ticker)
    plt.ylabel('SEK@close')
```